# Mongoose how to save document inside an array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a model which looks like this:

**User.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var memberSchema = new Schema({
        email: { 
            type: String, 
            required: true, 
            unique: true 
        },
        password: { 
            type: String, 
            required: true,
            min: 8
        }
});

var userSchemaPrimary = new Schema({
    team_code : {
        type: String, 
        required: true, 
        unique: true 
    },
    members:[memberSchema],
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchemaPrimary);

module.exports = User;
```

And this is how am trying to save

```
var User = require('../models/user');
var newTeam = new User({
    team_code : 'CODE01',
    members:
        {
            email: req.body.email,
            password: pass
        }
});

newTeam.save(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('User saved successfully!');
    return res.send("Done");
});
```

**When executed, throws model validation error.**
Well I tried to save data without the array documents, then its saves successfully. But when I try to save the array (array "members"), it throws validation error.

**I WANT TO**

Store data in the following way:

```
{
   team_code: "CODE01",
   members: [
      {
         email: "test01@email.com",
         password: "11111111"
      },
      {
         email: "test02@email.com",
         password: "22222222"
      }
      {
         email: "test03@email.com",
         password: "33333333"
      }
   ]
}
```

I dont understand what is going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `password` field in Schema is String, but you are saving Number, maybe that's a problem

Comment: No no its just an example I have given, am saving string

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning object to `members` field, but it's an array

```
var newTeam = new User({
    team_code : 'CODE01',
    members: [{
            email: req.body.email,
            password: pass
    }] // <-- note the array braces []
});
```

Comment: So whats the solution?